# Number of five letter words possible using the english alphabet, not including anagrams

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I'm studying for an intro to combinatorics midterm by completing past midterms.  One of the questions is "How many ways are there to choose $5$-letter 'words' from the $26$-letter English alphabet with repeated letters allowed, but anagrams of other words are not allowed?  For example, $\text{TREES}$ is an anagram of $\text{RESET}$, and $\text{AAABB}$ is an anagram of $\text{BABAA}$.  The words need not be English language words."

I know that there are $26^5$ possible words that can be formed.  I'm getting stuck with how to remove the total number of anagrams from this amount.  Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if all the letters of the word are different, we can choose $5$ letters with $\binom{26}{5}$ and since permutation of the letters are not counted, that's all we have.

For $4$ different letters, we can choose $4$ letters with $\binom{26}{4}$ and choose repeated letter with $\binom{4}{1}$. Therefore, we have $\binom{26}{4}\binom{4}{1}$ words in this case.

For $3$ different letters (can be chosen with $\binom{26}{3}$), we have two cases: Either two of the letters are repeated twice (can be chosen with $\binom{3}{2}$) or one of the letters is repeated three times (can be chosen with $\binom{3}{1}$). Therefore, we have $\binom{26}{3}\big[\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{1}\big]$ words in this case.

I think idea is clear after the above case distinction. There are two more cases for $2$ different letters and for only $1$ letter.

Comment: When you say "all the letters are different", do you mean every letter in the English alphabet are distinct, or all of the letters in a given word are distinct?

Comment: I meant $5$ letters of the word are distinct. I edited that part.

Comment: We're allowed to have words with the same letter in them.  AAAAA is counted as a word

Comment: Yes, those words will be counted in the case for only $1$ letter mentioned at the end of answer. I didn't write the last two cases but if you have some doubts, I can add them.

Comment: Oh I understand now.  Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome :) Good luck!